# code.interact() shuts when multiprocessing

Tags: python

Interactive console doesn't work in multiprocessing

Python 3.6

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import code

def t_interactive():
    code.interact(local=locals())

if __name__=="__main__":
    t2=Process(target=t_interactive)
    t2.start()
    t2.join()
```

I want to make a program to run on the background while a user is using interpreter, but it keeps exiting itself.

Comment: Use a thread instead of a new process.

Comment: Alternatively, put the interaction in the parent process and whatever other computation in the child.